# colorbox around parbox too big

Tags: boxes, backgrounds

I want to typset some text with colored background *and* outline, that spans the whole `\textwidth`. I tried to get this with a `colorbox` surrounding a `parbox`. It works in some way, but the `colorbox` is always a bit bigger than the `parbox`, causing the colored fill to overlap the outline a bit:
[image: colored fill overlaps outline]

Is there any way to fix this? I didn't find one. The corresponding code:

```
\newcommand{\information}[1]{\colorbox{DarkOliveGreen2}{\fboxsep4mm\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\parbox{\linewidth}{\textbf{foo: } #1}}}}
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** As supposed in the comments: I already tried removing or changing the `\fboxsep`-value, but it doesn't change the behavior. Just the space between the text and the border of the boxes tightens, and I want that space...

Comment: You forgot the `\fboxsep` value, i.e. it's too large

Comment: you use `\fboxsep4mm` so you can change it

Comment: You say you didn't find anything but where did you look:-) any documentation that tells you about \colorbox should tell you that it uses `\fboxsep`

Comment: The fboxsep before the framebox sets the padding for the frame you need to set it (to 0pt) before the colorbox if you don't want extra padding for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space between the box edges and the real content is ruled by `\fboxsep` as for the usual `\fbox` command.

Since `\fboxsep4mm` appears explicitly in the `\information` macro definition there's no chance to change the `\fboxsep` value before. `4mm` seems to be definitely too much, but this is a matter of taste, of course.

In my point of view, there's no need of using an additional `\framebox` command, since `\fcolorbox` is also available.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\begin{document}


\newcommand{\information}[2][0pt]{%
  \fboxsep=#1%
  \par\noindent%
  \fcolorbox{black}{DarkOliveGreen2}{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\textbf{foo: }#2}%
  }% Reduce the box size by 2 \fboxsep and 2\fboxrule widths. 
}


\information[2pt]{Foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `Overfull \hbox (17.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 13--14` (15pt indent and 2pt you just added with fboxsep :(

Comment: post early to keep egreg out? worth a try:-)

Comment: he will if you don't set fboxsep to 0pt on the outside and 4mm on the inside:-)

Comment: @LukeLR: Well, smarter? .... depends.. Anyway, I would suggest to use `tcolorbox` or `mdframed` rather than using `\colorbox`, but the later requires a smaller package, that's an advantage of `\colorbox` of course

Answer (score 4):

You need to control the padding of `\framebox` and `\colorbox` separately:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\begin{document}


\newcommand{\information}[1]{{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\par\noindent
\colorbox{DarkOliveGreen2}{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{4mm}%
\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\parbox{\linewidth}{\textbf{foo: } #1}}}}}


\information{Foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I followed your comment above the original post and used the following code: `\newcommand{\information}[1]{\fboxsep0mm\colorbox{DarkOliveGreen2}{\fboxsep4mm\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\parbox{\linewidth}{\textbf{foo: } #1}}}}` That did the trick! The idea to control the seps independently fixed it! Thanks!